# Multiple Jquery Causing to Stop One Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am an intermediate user of Java Scriptiong , Jquery, PHP and HTML.
I am trying to develop a website that has multiple scripts.
Individually the scripts are working fine. But when I ad WOW Slider Script, it causes the menu script effects and slider to stop working.

I have uploaded incomplete website at my friend's webspace. 
Please have a look at the page:
www.inetstudies.com/perfect/index.html

Comment: First step of debugging js: check your browser console for errors. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: Dear Varga
Thanx for prompt response.
Plz have a look at this page:
www.inetstudies.com/perfect/index.html

Comment: By default, the image slider has stopped working, menu effects have been disappeared, but the wow slider at the bottom (Hot Properties Section) is perfectly working.

Comment: When I delete this line:
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>

the image slider start scrolling and the menu effect appears, but the wow slider stopped working.

Plz help me to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This may not solve the issue, but will probably help - your references are incorrect:

The requested URL /universal-css-templates/m-15062010a/js/jquery.featureCarousel.min.js was not found on this server.

Fix this and you should be good to go. It is expecting to find some javascript 'jquery.featureCarousel.min.js' within your /universal-css-templates/m-15062010a/js/ directory, but fails. This is line 40 of your html.

visit here and you will see: [image]

Also you are including JQuery twice, once with this line (version 1.4):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

and again with this one (version 1.11):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
```

If you exclude this later, the other jquery stuff will work, but wow is unlikely to as the version is too old. Have you tried commenting out the inclusion of the 1.4.2 jquery?

Other bugs found include:
-- the inclusion of the 10th Content twice:

```
<!-- 10th Content -->
            <div id="fragment-10" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide" style="">
              <h2>Perfect Properties</h2>
              <p>...<br/>
              ...<br/>
              ...<br/>
              </p>
              <p><a class="btn_get_started" href="#">Get Started</a> <a class="btn_learn_more" href="#"></a></p>
            </div>
```

I just tried your site again, and the wowslider (the 3 window thing at the bottom left) is working, but the top piece is not. This might be fixed by removing the old jquery part.

Comment: Thanx Browne for your reply.
I have uploaded the desired file. Plz go through again.

Comment: I just retried this and am seeing the same thing in the network tab of the tools. Are you running behind a caching service/web service that needs restarting/resetting?

Comment: If you are using either IE, Firefox or Chrome, they all have built in tools that help you see all the assets that are being downloaded. If you look for the responses, this is what the server is sending to the browser. Usually you will see a http 404, but your apache webserver is catching the 404 and gracefully presenting an html page with the 404 for resources not found. This means it shows as a 200 in the network, but as you see from the response, it shows a 404 page being sent.

Comment: Dear Browne
As I have already mentioned that I am new to Jquery and other website development tools.
I dont have Apache Server installed on my machine. When I open this file in editor (dream viewer), it shows the same page as you captured above.
Now I have paused the line for this code: e.g.
<!--
<script src="js/jquery.featureCarousel.min.html" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
-->
But the problems still persist.
Plz help and oblige.

Comment: Now it shows only this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
juizDropDownMenu-1.5.min.js:10

Comment: jquery https://jquery.com/ is currently at v1.11.2 which is the version you need for wowSlider. The version expected for dropdownmenu is only fixed for v1.7 (last update of dropdownmenu code this was 26/ June 2012). I would suspect that you need to see if you can get wowslider to work on v1.7, and if not find yourself a different module for the dropdownmenu.

Comment: I just noticed you are also using v1.5 of the dropdownmenu js, try v2.0

Comment: Dear Browne: My hands are up. I am unable to do this.
Plz download the files and help me get rid of this issue. And send me the package in a zip file plzzzzzz.